# Weak formulation of a stationary Schrodinger equation on $ H^1_W(\mathbb{R}^n) $

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, greens-theorem

I need to find the weak formulation of this equation on $ H^1_W(\mathbb{R}^n) $ the weighted Sobolev space.

$$ \left(\dfrac{-1}{2m}\Delta + V(x) - \lambda\right)u = f $$

With $V(x)$ bounded from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I want to multiply the equation by a test function $ v \in H^1_W(\mathbb{R}^n) $ and integrate by parts using Green's identity but as far as I know I can only use the latter on a bounded region of $ \mathbb{R}^n $. Any indications ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $w \in A_p$ is a "nice" weight function. Then, you can find a sequence $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that
$$
v_n \to v
$$
in $H^1_w(\mathbb{R}^n)$. You can find this result for example here: https://www.jams.jp/scm/contents/Vol-10-1/10-6.pdf.
But then it is just standard procedure:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} v_n \Delta u \; dx=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \nabla v_n \cdot \nabla u \; dx.
$$
To conclude and pass to the limit on both sides, you need to have a condition on your weight function, which ensures, for example, that $H^1_w(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a continuous embedding. You can finde maybe inspiration here: https://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol19/kilpelai.pdf.

I should mention that weighted sobolev spaces usually arise in the context of an elliptic operator of the form
$$
-\nabla \cdot (w(x)A(x)\nabla u(x)),
$$
however, in your case, you would just end up with $A(x)$ to be the identity and more importantly $w(x)=\frac{1}{2m}$ which is constant. The norm on your weighted Sobolev space is equivalent to the standard norm and hence doesnt make much of a difference. With more information, I could probably give a better answer as well.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the explanation. The weighted sobolev space I have is 
$H^1_W(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n) / (1+|.|^2)^{1/2}u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$  

equipped with the norm $<u,v>_W=(\nabla u,\nabla v) + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}((1+|x|^2)u(x)v(x)dx$

Comment: This is not the "standard" definition of weighted Sobolev space, as the weight should also appear in the gradient term, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \nabla u(x) \cdot \nabla v(x) w(x) dx$. In this case, a more elementary approach might even be possible, but I dont have the time to figure it out right now.

Comment: I quoted some advanced machinery in here, but this problem can probably be dealt with using the Fourier transform or Sobolev embeddings in a clever way.

Comment: alright, thanks for the hints !

Comment: No problem, if these hints dont help you any further, let me know and I can take another look.